# Is there a way to trigger the browsers default "scroll to cursor" behaviour when when typing in a textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, textarea, contenteditable

I want to trigger the browsers default behaviour of jumping to the cursor when someone starts to write and the cursor is of screen.

At the moment, if I resize the cursor is off screen and I want to center the scrollbar on the cursor again after the resize.

When I resize and type the scrollbar automatically jumps to the right position. Is there a way to trigger that "jump to cursor" behaviour with vanilla javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) to select the focused element and [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView) :

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  element = document.activeElement;
  element.scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

```css
div{
  height:200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Sadly that does not scroll to the current cursor position. Thank you though :)

Comment: I edited my answer with a working snippet. Focus the input at the very bottom of the snippet and get back up the page. 5 sec after, it will focus the input. All you have to do now is edit when the code will trigger.

Comment: In Chrome this moves the code snippet to the top of the page,

what I meant is, the editor is on screen and has an overflow, on resize of the editor the scrollbar of the editor scrolls the cursor off screen. It snaps to the cursor when I type. Thats what I want to simulate :)

Comment: Do you have an example of your situation? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: I have an contenteditable editor that is e.g. 50px wide and has a fixed max height of 100 px. Now if there is an overflow, a scrollbar will show so you can scroll the text. When I write, the browser automatically jumps to the cursor position so the user can see what he/she is writing.

If I resize the editor width to e.g. 100px, the content now moves and reflows with the new size, but the cursor is now in the not visible area. When I type the browser jumps to it again, but I want to scroll the cursor to the visible area in my resize function. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hm try something like this:

```
$('.element').keydown(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).focus();   
});
```

Comment: The problem is, this triggers on a keydown, I want to simulate the keydown "scroll to caret" behaviour though. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Basically yes, on Element resize the scrollbar should jump to the cursor position in the contenteditable :)

Comment: If i get it right you want to use either:  $('item').keydown(); or $('item').focus() at the $(window).resize() event ???

Comment: Kind of yes, I want to trigger the browsers "jump to active cursors when typing" behaviour :)